# How to show country wise price InApp Purchase V3?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

In my android app, I am showing the price of purchase products on my custom buttons. I want to show those prices according to the country for eg. if the app opens at Indian price should be in INR, if it opens at US price should be in USD etc.

**I tried**

```
private void getSkuDetails(Inventory inventory) {

        for (int i = 0; i < myData.INAPP_SKUS.length; i++) {

            SkuDetails skuDetails = inventory.getSkuDetails(myData.INAPP_SKUS[i]);

            if (skuDetails != null) {
                System.out.println(">>>> Price::::" + skuDetails.getPrice());
                System.out.println(">>>> Type::::" + skuDetails.toString());
            } else {
                System.out.println(">>>>> It is null.....");
            }
        }
    }
```

but always `skuDetails` comes `null` for every SKU.

- I have also published my app in play store and test this. but still, I am getting null `skuDetail`.

So, How to display these In-App products price according to the country?

Comment: Read [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1169947) and [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3539140?visit_id=0-636475271429419297-3274706013&rd=1) .may you can get clear view about multiple currencies

Comment: They said that they are generating price for multiple countries I know that. But thing is, when I am trying to get those prices and country code from code I am getting skuDetail.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple strings file like ta, en suffix.

use the following string in different language/Country string files

for Indian rupees

```
<string name="currency_symbol">\u20B9</string>
```

for Euro sign

```
<string name="currency_symbol">&#8364;</string>
```

For other signs refer this link, it will help you...

**for More information**

Link 1: https://gist.github.com/bzerangue/5484121

Link 2: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: I don't think this is feasible solution because like this way I have to list out all countries' symbols and calculate prices according to that and then I can fetch those after getting country of device. Instead I want to use api provided by google, I used that too but don't know why I am getting null.

Answer (score 0):

first,make sure you can make a purchase in your app.
second,you can try to clear your google play sotre cache.

the getSkuDetails API will return the correct price and currency depends on user's ip or credit card country.
if you don't config wrong,you won't get the null result.